# Can you get the url (and params) of the initial navigation, before navigating?

Tags: angular, typescript

Basically I want to navigate to a special site, when a condition for the url is true.

Imagine the following `ngOnInit()` in `app.component.ts`:

```
if (urlMatchesCondition()) {
    await this.router.navigateByUrl('special-site');
} else {
    await this.router.initialNavigation();
}
```

Logging the `ActivatedRoute` (`await this.route.url.pipe(take(1)).toPromise()`) and `Router` (`this.router.url`) log an empty route, or "/" respectively.

Lets say, I would want to check if the route contains "test", how could I do that?

Comment: Do you mean that if your app is called with `/test` but it's not a valid route, then default route applies and you don't have access to the initial route asked by the user?

Comment: No i mean that for example I get parameters with the url (eg. `/test/123`) and depending on that parameter, I will navigate the user to some place. @GaëlJ

Comment: And `/test/` is defined as a route in your routing? I really don't get it

Comment: Yes `/test` is a route, as well as `/test/{param}`. Which part don't you get? Both routes should work. Initial navigation is done manually ([using `initialNavigation` parameter](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions)). But before the initial navigation, I would like to check if the route contains a special parameter. @GaëlJ

Answer (score 0):

On the `ActivatedRoute` you have access to all the parameters through `queryParamMap` for instance, or the path.. depending on what you want to check for.

By the way if you only care about the current value, you can use `.snapshot` to get a value rather than an `Observable`.

---

Moreover, I think your use case fits better what is called a "guard" in Angular which allow to do some checks before actually loading components and optionally redirect to somewhere else.

Comment: `ActivatedRoute` only updates when the initial navigation is made, so I cannot use it before. A Guard is not really suitable for the use case.

Comment: I probably didn't understand your question then. When do you want to check for the route URL/parameters? At 1st load of the app? At each route change?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain something correctly. Should be done only on app load.